# Is it possible to hide the file name of a ref when used in schema definition?

Tags: openapi, redoc

My openapi.yml file endpoint looks like this:

```
/v2/myendpoint:
  get:
    summary: Retrieve stuff
    requestBody:
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '../schemas/my_get_request.json'
```

Within `my_get_request.json` I reference a definition in a `common.json` file.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://january.com/schemas/v0.2.1/my_get_request.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "MyGetRequest",
    "properties": {
        "unique_ID": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "randomdescription"
        },
        "status": {
            "$ref": "common.json#/$defs/blahStatus"
        },
```

When I use Redocly to generate a static webpage, next to `status` I see `string(blahStatus)` is it possible to hide `string(blahStatus)` from showing so users don't see my internal naming of definitions in `common.json`?

Answer (score 0):

In case this question is still legit, the solution is to use the `hideSchemaTitles` option of ReDoc CLI.

```
hideSchemaTitles - do not display schema title next to to the type
```

See https://github.com/Redocly/redoc#redoc-options-object for reference.